# Redirecting to previous page after login? Mojolicious

Tags: perl, redirect, mojolicious

The title pretty much summarizes exactly my problem. I have my login controller, and I'd like to redirect to previous page after login. E.g., If I am viewing the Contact Us page, then I log in, I'd like to be redirected back to the Contact Us page. Just wondering the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you show us code?

Comment: No, I haven't tried anything because I'm not really sure where to start on this. I was thinking about grabbing referer from the header and then doing a redirect_to on that, but I'm not really sure that's the best method for doing this.

I really don't see why you need to see any code for this question.

Comment: Checking the headers is a fine start. Alternatively you could add some parameter to the login form that is set on each page, and then send the user back to that page.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are there are pros and cons of one option vs the other? I'm not asking for code, I understand how to do the code part, just trying to understand the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: Well, the parameter requires you to always have that parameter. That's something visible to the user. But a lot of websites do it. So no problem there. The referrer will basically do the same, but without that visibility. In each case, make sure to check if it's there and if it's local, and decide what to do if not. E.g. the user might have bookmarked the login page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could check referrer.

```
$controller->redirect_to($controller->req->headers->referrer);
```

Comment: Unless the referer is the login page itself, as might be the case if you type in wrong username/password and get redirected back to the login page.

Comment: Also do not forget to check that you refer back to your site and not to third party

Answer (score 2):

It is maybe not as beautiful solution as the one above, but I use a parameter to pass the url of 'previous' page (back_url). If the parameter is empty, I can setup a default page to land on.

```
my $self = shift;
my $back_url = $self->param('back_url');
$back_url = '/publications' if $back_url eq $self->req->url->to_abs or $back_url eq '';
# code here
$self->redirect_to($back_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

based on [Chankey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33169008/1681985) , [alexk's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33167200/#comment54175320_33169008) and [Eugen's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33167200/#comment68918567_33169008)

```perl
$app->helper(redirect_to_referrer_or_homepage => sub {
    my ($c) = @_;

    if (my $r = $c->req->headers->referrer) {
        $c->app->log->debug('Referrer: ' . $r);

        # both to_abs for comparison
        $r = Mojo::URL->new($r)->to_abs;
        my $login = $c->url_for('login')->to_abs;

        # Eugen's: check that you refer back to your site and not to third party
        if ($r->host eq $login->host) {

            # alexk's: Unless the referer is the login page itself
            unless ($r eq $login) {
                $c->redirect_to($r);
                return; # bail
            }
        }
    }

    $c->redirect_to('/');
});
```

to be used like:

```perl
$r->get('/login' => sub {
    my $c = shift;
    if (...) {
        $c->redirect_to_referrer_or_homepage();
        return; # bail
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
})->name('login');
```